# Elasticsearch searching names with middle initial

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the [Elasticsearch DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library within a Django project. The primary query is:

```
s.query("multi_match", query=query, type='phrase', fields=['name', 'title'])
```

Searching `'Joe Gray'` returns anybody named `'Joe Gray'`. But searching 'Joe Gray' does not return any names with `'Joe B Gray'` or `'Joe W Gray'`. Is there a way I can modify my query to search by first and last name, but display results with middle initials?

Comment: To anybody looking at this problem, the solution I came up with is to add phrase_slop=1 to the query. So like this:

s = s.query("multi_match", query=query, type='phrase', phrase_slop=1, fields=['name', 'title'])

Now searching 'Joe Gray' will return results with the name 'Joe B Gray'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name search can be tricky. Some things to consider:

1. The order matters, so I understand why you used a phrase query, but having complex phrase queries is in my opinion not an elegant search solution. You can boost this at index or query time by creating a sub-field that preserves the order (i.e. no tokenization).
2. Capitalization (case-sensitive) probably does not change the meaning of a name.
3. The search for initials and some character normalization.
4. Synonyms, e.g. William is often the same as Bill, Richard is the same as Dick, etc.

So thinking about a solution. Going for multiple fields is the way to go. And what is your query language? Do you want to have users want to use a wildcard or do you want to make this dummy proof? I assume you go for the latter approach...

- You probably want the original name for display and the match on the original string should receive the highest boost, with i.e. `"type":  "keyword"`. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html
- but you also want to support case-sensitive search in a sub-field called `name.lowercase` (see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html)
- create initials before you index. I can image that `Joe Bernard Gray` could be equivalent to `Joe B. Gray`. Perhaps you want to create a field called `name.normalized` where you also add the value `Joe B. Gray` in `name.normalized` for `Joe Bernard Gray`. Apply case-folding for `name.normalized`. And punctuation is not needed. I.B.M is probably the same as IBM using the `char filter` for `name.normalized` and possible also `name.lowercase`, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html
- If you have non-English names, you probably want to normalize the characters with `ascii folding` in `name.normalized`, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html
- Perhaps add the `Synonym Token Filter` to the `name.normalized` field, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html
- And last but not least, use the `Shingle Token` filter to find multiple combinations of the same names in `name.normalized`, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html

So you will have:

- name (highest boost), name.lowercase (high boost), name.normalized (no boost).

By setting up a more advanced mapping, you can avoid writing complicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the query to be of type "phrase". Removing the `type='phrase'` parameter should solve your problem. 
When you specify `type='phrase'`, Elasticsearch matches the entire phrase using `match_phrase` query. The tokens need to be in the same position as in the query to match.
The default behaviour for type in multi_match is `best_fields` which should be fine for your use-case.